# Django 1.5: How to use generic views?

Tags: django, django-generic-views, django-1.5

I am trying to use the Generic Views in Django 1.5 and its kind of confusing.
So far I have been using functions within views.py. I agree that the function approach has more boilerplate code, but at the same time you have more control over it as a developer. Nonetheless for sake of learning. Let consider this partial code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'invitation' in request.session:
            invitation = Invitation.objects.get(id=request.session['invitation'])
            profile = invitation.sender.get_profile()            
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, is_accept_invite = True, _email = invitation.email)
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        ...
```

The way I understand it, A generic view considers three states: GET, POST -> Valid, POST -> invalid().

But the code above is POST -> condition before form.validation to instantiate the form accordingly

This would be a generic view that I came up with:

```
class RegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'register.html'
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = '/registration_successfull/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        ...
```

I suppose I need to override `get_form(form_class)` or `get_form_kwargs()` to check for my request.session and instantiate the RegistrationForm accordingly. Is that correct?  Is there any example how to do that? I couldnt find any example on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'register.html'
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = '/registration_successfull/'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(RegisterView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        if 'invitation' in self.request.session:
            kwargs['invitation'] = invitation = Invitation.objects.get(id=self.request.session['invitation'])
            kwargs['profile'] = invitation.sender.get_profile()
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        ...
```

Comment: This sounds promising. Give me one day to test this before accept it as an answer. Many Thanks